# ItemsControl in HubSection not 100% height

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps

Can anyone explain what's going on here. The two news articles in this WrapGrid aren't taking up the full space available to them as visible in the image below

[image: WrapGrid]
My xaml looks like this

```
<HubSection Header="{Binding SportArticles[0].Title}" Background="{Binding SportArticles[0].Image}" MaxWidth="1000" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ItemsControl
                     x:Name="xItems" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ScoreNewsArticleTemplate}" ItemsSource="{Binding SportArticles}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch">
                        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <VariableSizedWrapGrid Orientation="Vertical" ItemWidth="350"/>
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    </ItemsControl>
                </DataTemplate>
            </HubSection>
```

The outer blue box is the HubSection and the inner blue box is the ItemsControl. I can't understand why its not taking up the full space available

Comment: Try setting `<VariableSizedWrapGrid Orientation="Vertical" ItemWidth="350" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>`

Comment: The next thing to try is setting the `VerticalContentAlignment` of your `ItemsControl`'s `ItemContainerStyle` to stretch. I'm going to add it as an answer so that the style stays the same. We can continue debugging over there.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `VerticalContentAlignment` of your `ItemContainerStyle` to `Stretch`.

```
<ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    </Style>
</ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Comment: Error 1 The member "HorizontalContentAlignment" is not recognized or is not accessible.